# Excel 2010: Find first non-blank cell based on changing column headings

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that contains dates in the future and in the past. I want to find a formula that will find the first non-blank cell from todays date and enter it into the column last test. I do not want to include future information and everyday it will automatically update based on todays date.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, too many words. Can you edit your post and insert a screenshot? Mock up the desired result. You won't have enough reputation to post the screenshot, but post the link, anyway. Then comment here and I'll fix it up.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment, I have changed my post so hopefully you will understand what I am trying to achieve and have also included a screenshot.

Comment: What happens on 8th April? Will you insert new columns with dates between "last test" and 7th April?

Comment: How come there is a number already entered for 6th April? It's in the future, so why does it have an entry? Also, do you want the date of the  most recent test or do you want the percentage number in the "last test" column?

Comment: It will have hypothetical data in it for training purposes which is why there will be future information. In the actual spreadsheet there will be a lot more columns before today's date (a year or so) and columns will be added if necessary. I want the percentage number in the "last test" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Start in cell B2 with

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(2:2,MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0)):INDEX(2:2,99),MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(INDEX(2:2,MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0)):INDEX(2:2,99)),0)),"not tested")
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, then copy down.

[image]